# How to remove comma parsing of strings in a CSV

Tags: python

I wrote the following code and I encountered an error where the CSV file wrote to using each of the items in a list, each entry is parsed.

Source Code:

```
import requests
import sys
import csv


bus = []
final = []
url = 'https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search'
api_key = '**censored**'
headers = {
    'Authorization':'Bearer ' + api_key
}
params = {
    'term': 'coffee',
    "location": sys.argv[1]
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
businesses = response.json()['businesses']
for business in businesses:
    bus.append(business['name'])

for item in bus:
    final.append(item)

final = []
    

print('The top 10 coffee shops are: ')
for item in bus[0:10]:
    print(item)

with open('coffee_shops.csv', 'w+') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow('name')
    for item in bus:
        writer.writerow(item)
```

CSV Output:
n,a,m,e

J,a,y, ,J,e,a,n, ,C,a,f,e

L,e,g,e,n,d,s, ,C,a,f,�

C,o,s,t,a, ,C,o,f,f,e,e

T,h,e, ,F,i,g, ,L,e,a,f

O,r,l,i, ,E,s,p,e,e,s,s,o, ,B,a,r, ,B,a,k,e,r,y

C,a,f,e, ,2,3

T,i,p,p,y,s, ,C,a,f,e

A,u,n,t, ,S,a,l,l,y, ,C,a,f,e

B,e,l,g,i,q,u,e

C,o,f,f,e,e,7

B,u,n,n,o, ,C,o,f,f,e,e

C,o,s,t,a, ,C,o,f,f,e,e

C,a,k,e,s, ,a,n,d, ,S,h,a,k,e,s

T,h,e, ,D,e,l,i,c,i,o,u,s, ,C,a,f,e, ,S,a,n,d,w,i,c,h, ,B,a,r

C,a,f,f,e, ,L,a,t,t,e, ,B,a,r,k,i,n,g

C,a,k,e,s, ,&, ,B,a,k,e,s

C,a,f,e, ,C,h,i,c,c,h,i

D,e,l,i,c,i,o,u,s, ,C,a,f,e

L,i,t,t,l,e, ,W,o,o,d,f,o,r,d, ,C,a,f,e

P,o,r,k,y,s

Is there a way to remove the commas?

Thanks
Amen

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  
This includes - what is the input, expected output and current state along with any other contextual information.

Comment: `writer.writerow('name')` is certainly bad. The method expects an iterable of columns! A string is an iterable over its chars, making each char its own column. What you rather want is `writer.writerow(['name'])`. Same goes for `item`...

Comment: You are supposed to pass a list of values to `writer.writerow`, e.g., `writer.writerow(['bob', 'jane'])`.

Comment: YES! Thank you schwobaseggl Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your issue, you have a list of strings in a list named `bus` and you want to save this list to a file.

```
bus = ['A', 'B', 'C']
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('name\n')
    for item in bus:
        f.write(item + '\n')
```

out.txt

```
name
A
B
C
```